# Applying border top effects

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time achieving the desired effect shown here:

[image]

Basically apply border top effect to accordion buttons, but except for the very first one. Here's the html code:

```
<div class="cat">
    <h2>Accordion</h2>

    <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seemed to be maybe the following would work, but it didn't.

```css
.cat button:not(:first-child){ 
    border-top: solid 1px black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`:

```css
.cat button:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
}
```

```css
.cat button:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat">
  <h2>Accordion</h2>

  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>



  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>



  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`.

The `:first-child` selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent - which is not your case, because the first child in your container (`.cat`) is a `h2` element.

`:first-of-type` matches first child in a parent, but of particular type.